# Does moving setOnClickListener content to function is the same?

Tags: java, performance, android-studio

I want to organize my code in different way and I am not sure if it is the same  efficiency.

Does this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.editTextLogin);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("go", "This button clicked");
        }
    });
}
```

Equal this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.editTextLogin);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(listener());
}
private View.OnClickListener listener(){
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("go", "This button clicked");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You will have one more method call so yes it will be like a few nanoseconds slower. Or with other words it does not matter at all. Both variants are totally fine.